# Running Powershell PS1 on MAC (WMI? DB?)

Tags: macos, powershell

I have a custom .Ps1 file provided by 3rd party vendor to create DB. I have installed pwershell on my MAC using BREW but when running the ps1. I´m getting the below error.

> The term 'Get-WmiObject' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Any pointer to sort this

Comment: Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) is the infrastructure for management data and operations on **Windows-based** operating systems.

Comment: In addition to what @JosefZ said, the CIM cmdlets provide almost exactly the same functionality as the WMI cmdlets.  Look at Get-CIMInstance as a replacement for Get-WMIObject.

Comment: @MikeShepard There's no cim commands in osx either.

Comment: Didn't know that,@js2010.  Now I do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no wmi or cim commands in powershell for osx.  Maybe you could use a commandline mysql or sqlite3 depending on the database?